# How to terminate ruby function execution if it takes too long time to work?

Tags: ruby, timeout, execution, terminate

I have some ruby code like this:

```
result1 = function_1(params)
result2 = function_2(params)
result3 = function_3(params)
```

But sometimes some of them can take too much time to work (this functions are depends on internet connection speed). I need to terminate execution of function if it takes more then 5 second. How I should do it with ruby-way?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
require 'timeout'
timeout_in_seconds = 20
begin
  Timeout::timeout(timeout_in_seconds) do
    #Do something that takes long time
  end
rescue Timeout::Error
  # Too slow!!
end
```

Comment: Ruby is awesome... seriously

Answer (score 7):

You could use [Timeout](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/timeout/rdoc/Timeout.html).

```
require 'timeout'
status = Timeout::timeout(5) {
  # Something that should be interrupted if it takes too much time...
}
```